# basecamp 2 get trashed persons events

Tags: basecamp

I am getting all the history from Basecamp and putting it into a database. However when I get everybody events history it doesn't include people who have been removed and are in the trashed folder.

I used "people/trashed.json" to get everyone who has been trashed. However when I put in their id like "people/**userID**/events.json" it comes back with nothing, I also tried "people/trashed/**userID**/events.json" but still nothing. On the api documentation (https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/people.md) it mentions how to get the people who are in the trashed part but not if it is possible to get their events history.

Does anyone know if getting a trashed persons event history is possible and if so how do you get it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found to get the data is to go through every campaign and get their events. The events include ones from the people who are trashed. Also if you get the id's of the campaigns that are trashed you can still get the events off them, therefore it might be a bit tedious but you are able to get all of the events of trashed people this way.

Lets hope there is a better way in Basecamp 3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible. I removed one user and invited him again, but the new user profile has different id. I also do not see an option to move user from trash.

My idea was to add user again to one, test project and delete again after fetching events.

You can try to [ask Basecamp support about it](https://basecamp.com/support).